# Creating dataframe from values in a logfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider below mentioned logfile :

```
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 C: FORW 0x00 Ok MTE GETUESTATUS
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 ELAPSED_TIME:      125.0 s
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 UE_ID: 0         UE_GROUP_ID: 0, 0
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 RRC_STATE:       CONNECTED           FREQ: 21400     CELL_ID: 30
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 NAS_STATE:       REGISTERED                          PLMN: 10001F
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 DTE_STATE:
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 [Host]         [IP]                                [APN]                                        [App]
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 pppoe_00000_0  192.168.2.3                         defaultmnc001mcc100gprs                  -
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 MTS_MOBILITY_STATE:
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 MM_ID: 0   PATH_ID: 0   POS: (12, 5)   V: 0.5   NEXT_WP: (25, 8)
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 [FREQ]    [CELL_ID]    [R]    [PL]    [RSRP]    [RSRQ]    [SIR]    [CQI]    [Radio Context]
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 21400     30           200    61      -70       -11.2     9.6      8        0
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 MTS_TRAFFIC_STATE:
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 [TM_ID]    [TM_STATE]       [TP]   [SERVICES]
02/05/21 19:45:00:712 0          ATTACHED         0      - 
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 C: FORW 0x00 Ok MTE GETUESTATUS
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 ELAPSED_TIME:      126.0 s
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 UE_ID: 0         UE_GROUP_ID: 0, 0
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 RRC_STATE:       CONNECTED           FREQ: 21400     CELL_ID: 30
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 NAS_STATE:       REGISTERED                          PLMN: 10001F
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 DTE_STATE:
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 [Host]         [IP]                                [APN]                                        [App]
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 pppoe_00000_0  192.168.2.3                         defaultmnc001mcc100gprs                  -
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 MTS_MOBILITY_STATE:
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 MM_ID: 0   PATH_ID: 0   POS: (13, 5)   V: 0.5   NEXT_WP: (25, 8)
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 [FREQ]    [CELL_ID]    [R]    [PL]    [RSRP]    [RSRQ]    [SIR]    [CQI]    [Radio Context]
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 21400     30           200    61      -70       -11.2     9.6      8        0
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 MTS_TRAFFIC_STATE:
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 [TM_ID]    [TM_STATE]       [TP]   [SERVICES]
02/05/21 19:45:01:686 0          ATTACHED         0      -
```

I have to create a dataframe using this logfile which should have timestamp, rsrp, rsrq, cqi as shown below:

```
| Time        | RSRP | RSRQ | CQI |
|-------------|------|------|-----|
|19:45:00:712 | -70  | -11.2| 8   |
|19:45:01:686 | -70  | -11.2| 8   |
|19:45:02:704 | -71  | -11.3| 8   |
```

How can I do it using pandas?

Comment: Give a slightly larger sample of the log file. This small sample is not enough to generate any dataframe on our end.

Comment: Hi @Joshua, I have updated the question with 3 instances of the command in log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your file line by line. If a line matches the headers then the values are on the next line. Append all values to a list and convert it to dataframe and finally, cast your data to the right type.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

COLS = ['FREQ', 'CELL_ID', 'R', 'PL', 'RSRP', 'RSRQ', 'SIR', 'CQI', 'Radio Context']
# r'\[(FREQ|CELL_ID|R|PL|RSRP|RSRQ|SIR|CQI|Radio Context)\]'
LINE = re.compile(fr"\[({'|'.join(COLS)})\]")


data = []
with open('dumpfile.log') as logfile:
    for line in logfile:
        txt = line[22:].strip()  # headers
        if LINE.findall(line):
            line = next(logfile)
            dti = line[8:22].strip()  # time
            val = line[22:].split()  # values
            data.append([dti] + val)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time'] + COLS)
df[COLS] = df[COLS].astype(float)
```

```
>>> df[['Time', 'RSRP', 'RSRQ', 'CQI']]
           Time  RSRP  RSRQ  CQI
0  19:45:00:712 -70.0 -11.2  8.0
1  19:45:01:686 -70.0 -11.2  8.0
2  19:45:02:704 -71.0 -11.3  8.0
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, thanks for your answer. I want to collect only "%H:%M:%S:%f" in Time. In "dti" I could do;  dti = line[8:22].strip(). What other changes should I have to made?

Comment: @Avinash. I updated my solution according to your comment.